# Find and scroll to XML node in WPF WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, webbrowser-control

I'm writing a WPF app to load XML into the WebBrowser control (via the Navigate method) and also populate a Treeview with the XML nodes.  I have managed to do both of these without issue but what I need to do now is find and scroll to the node in the WebBrowser when I double click a particular node or element in the TreeView.

I suspect I can use XPath with a Javascript or DOM query but apart from that idea I have no idea to do what I need or if, once the node is found in the XML whether I can get the webbrowser control to scroll to it.  I've googled this for ages but can't see anything so far that shows me how to do this - can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Are youbtransforming your xml to html? There's a scrollintoview method you can use from javascript on an element. All you need to do is find the html element.https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

Comment: No, I'm just using webBrowser.Navigate(<xml file>) to load the XML straight from the file into the browser.  This then color codes the XML and gives the ability to expand and collapse the nodes. Therefore I do not think I can inject Javascript into the document or use the html DOM to search.  I'm thinking I may be able to use the MSXML library  for this but have been too busy at work to get back to it (this is strictly a side project at this stage).

Comment: I don't follow how msxml is going to allow you to scroll - which is internet explorer. I think you should be instead using xslt to transform to html. Which you can then have whatever javascript scripts you like defined in. Then your scrolling is a matter of calling that function on your page.

Comment: Ok, thanks Andy - I will have to investigate how to do that as I wasn't even aware you could do it.